# To deal with 'Boolean' values in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

Currently I'm using `Tinyint(1)` to indicate `Boolean` values in my MySQL databases, which I really don't like that. So, how could I store and retrieve `Boolean` values in my `MySQL` databases via `PHP`?

How to use it in `WHERE` clause and how to assign the value in `INSERT, UPDATE` queries properly?

When I have it back on PHP, it's `TRUE`, `true`, or simply `1`, if I'm gonna check that with `===`?

Also did you ever had any problem when you migrating from `Tinyint(1)` to `BOOLEAN`?

Thanks in advance. :)

**Update:**

I know that `Tinyint(1)` is the same as `Boolean`, however I want to work on `Boolean` data type instead of `Tinyint(1)`. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: `BOOL, BOOLEAN` are only **synonyms** for `TINYINT(1)` in MySQL.

Comment: thanks, yes I know that, but I want to work on `Boolean` in my PHP side, instead of `Tinyint`, that's why I'm asking the question ...

Comment: Though it depends on your methodology, you may need to cast the `true` `false` keywords to `int` when inserting into any int type. I do believe that some forms of prepared statements make this arrangement for you, but if your query is inline, then this is necessary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a boolean data type. Tinyint(1) is pretty close enough. Working with this in PHP is simple.

```
If (1) echo 'true'; // is the same as if (true)
// Just as
if (0) echo 'false'; // is the same as if (false)
```

And if you really really want a boolean value, you can do

```
// $mysql_data is tinyint value from db
$boolean = $mysql_data ? true : false;
// Now you have your boolean as $boolean
```

Comment: In MySQL, the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0 as explained [in mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 4):

With booleans, don't use `=== FALSE` - the value is already a boolean (unless the function requires you to use `===`, like `strpos()`). The value is booleanish - it's technically an integer, but PHP is a dynamic language, so it its not a problem.

Consider `preg_match()` function - it returns the number of matches (integer).

Would you prefer to write that?

```
if (preg_match('/\bregexp?\b/', $variable) === 1)
```

Or that?

```
if (preg_match('/\bregexp?\b/', $variable))
```

Obviously, the way without explicit `=== 1` is better. You ask if it matches, not if it has 0 matches. Also, if you think that `=== 1` is safer, why not do `=== 1 === TRUE`?

Of course, it's possible to convert values to booleans using `(bool)` or `!!`.

Also, in certain languages such as C or Perl, there is no difference between booleans and numbers. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="can_get" id="can_get" class="form-control">
                <option <?php if($can_get== "1"){ echo "selected"; } ?> 
value="1">True</option>
                <option <?php if($can_get== "0"){ echo "selected"; } ?> 
value="0">False</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: I use this It is working fine

Comment: OP already knows that he can use the integer to determine true or false in his PHP code. I don't think your answer adds anything new to this post